# How to get the scrollbars back in the VBA editor?

Tags: vba, userform, designer, vbe

My VBA editor used to have a vertical scroll bar on the right-hand side when I was editing a user form.  These let me move down in the form if it was longer than the screen size.  It has disappeared.

Alternatively, maybe there is a way to shrink view of the form to fit the screen?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Verify the form's `ScrollHeight`, `ScrollWidth`, and `Scrollbars` properties, that's what determines when. whether, and how scrollbars are rendered on a form.

Comment: Try executing the form (use the green RUN icon on your toolbar) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: That's not a *slider*. It's a *Scrollbar*.

Comment: Just to be clear - you're talking about a *design time* scrollbar in the *VB editor* window - not a scrollbar which is on the actual form at run time?

Comment: In the VBE try going to *Window >> Close all Windows* then double- click the form to open it in design view.  If you don't have the user forms's window maximised then you may not see scrollbars: double-click on the userform window header if that's the case.

Comment: Gordon and Ted:  Talking about scroll bars in VBE at design time.

Comment: Tim: Window >> has no option Close all Windows in my VBE.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody posted a question if had tried setting the scroll height larger than the form height.  The question has been removed, but that is the answer.  Thanks, all.